# How to compare two column words values from two dataframes, and create a new column containing matching/contained words?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**** UPDATED QUESTION ****

I have these two dataframes:

DF1

```
id type 
0  "car"
1  "travel"
2  "sport"
3  "Cleaning-bike"
4  "Build house"
5  "test 32 sport foot"
```

DF2

```
sentence_id sentence
0           "I love cars"
1           "I don't like traveling"
2           "I don't do sport and travel"
3           "I am on vacation"
4           "My bik needs more attention"
5           "I want a house"
6           "I know a lot about football"
```

I would to see for each row in DF1 type column, if this word appears in any row of DF2, create a new column 'category' in DF2 containing the word appearing in the row (list of words if several match like ['sport', 'travel']. And 'no match if nothing found from DF1.

How can I do this ? Without doing for each loop with contains() method. DF1 has thousands rows and DF2 millions.

**Sometimes type of DF1 doesn't match totally with sentence, but one of the category word is contained in the sentence (exemple "foot" is in the sentence with id 6)** **And also sometimes the sentence doesn't contains the total word of a type (exemple with 'bik').**

Expected output:

```
sentence_id     sentence                        category
    0           'I love cars'                   'car'
    1           "I don't like traveling"        'travel'
    2           "I don't do sport"              ['sport', 'travel']
    3           'I am on vacation'              'no match'
    4           "My bik needs more attention"  "Cleaning-bike"
    5           "I want a house"                "Build house"
    6           "I know a lot about football"   "test 32 sport foot"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all lists with [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
DF2['category'] = DF2['sentence'].str.findall('|'.join(DF1['type'].str.strip("'")))
print (DF2)
   sentence_id                       sentence         category
0            0                  'I love cars'            [car]
1            1       'I don't like traveling'         [travel]
2            2  'I don't do sport and travel'  [sport, travel]
3            3             'I am on vacation'               []
```

If need also scalars if length is `1` and custom string if empty string add custom function:

```
f = lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else 'no match' if len(x) == 0 else x
DF2['category'] = DF2['sentence'].str.findall('|'.join(DF1['type'].str.strip("'"))).apply(f)


print (DF2)
   sentence_id                       sentence         category
0            0                  'I love cars'              car
1            1       'I don't like traveling'           travel
2            2  'I don't do sport and travel'  [sport, travel]
3            3             'I am on vacation'         no match
```

EDIT: Create dictionary with split values by `-` or space in `DF1['type']` and match it in custom function:

```
s = DF1['type'].str.strip("'")

s = pd.Series(s.to_numpy(), index=s).str.split('-|\s+').explode().str.lower()
d = {v: k for k, v in s.items()}
print (d)
{'car': 'car', 
 'travel': 'travel', 
 'sport': 'sport',
 'cleaning': 'Cleaning-bike',
 'bike': 'Cleaning-bike',
 'build': 'Build house', 
 'house': 'Build house'}

pat = '|'.join(s)

def f(x):
    out = [d.get(y, y) for y in x]
    if len(out) == 1:
        return out[0]
    elif not bool(x):
        return 'no match'
    else:
        return out
```

---

```
DF2['category'] = DF2['sentence'].str.findall(pat).apply(f)
print (DF2)
   sentence_id                        sentence         category
0            0                   'I love cars'              car
1            1        'I don't like traveling'           travel
2            2   'I don't do sport and travel'  [sport, travel]
3            3              'I am on vacation'         no match
4            4  'My bike needs more attention'    Cleaning-bike
5            5                'I want a house'      Build house
```

Comment: Thanks, is it the same process if in DF1 type value I have several words like 'Cleaning-bike' ? If one of these two words appears in DF2 I would like to have it as a match

Comment: @codelifevcd - Now it match only both words if match like `I don't do sport and travel Cleaning-bike`

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question to be more clear

Comment: @codelifevcd - answer was edited.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post. I saw that sometimes type or sentence doesn't contains all the word but I would like to have it as a match if the type is contained in the sentence or word of a sentence is contained in a type. I don't know how to have it

Comment: @jezrael How can we optimise the code for larger dataframe?